# Login works from the second time only...session id keeps changing the first time

Tags: php, session, authentication, sessionid

When I login using pop.php it works and I'm redirected to the same page with the firstname showing on my nav bar. But as soon as I reload or change the page the session_id changes and all the session information goes away.
The folder on godaddy where session is saved is working and all the new sessions are getting saved there.

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'pop.php';
include 'connection.php';

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE hits SET page_hits=page_hits + 1 WHERE id=1");
?>
    <title>EdiFort - The Guide To Your Future</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- style -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo10.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fi/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/notify-metro.css"> 
<script src="js/notify-metro.js"></script>
    <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animated.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
              <script>
              new WOW().init();
              </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginLink").click(function( event ){
           event.preventDefault();
           $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
     });

    $(".overlayLink").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');

        $("#loginTarget").load("ajax/" + action);

        $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27 && $(".overlay").css("display") != "none" ) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>
    <!--styles -->
</head>
<body >
<?php 
    include 'popbox.php';?>
    <!-- page header -->
    <header class="only-color">
        <!-- header top panel -->
        <?php
        if(loggedin())
        {
            include 'loginwelcom.php';
        }
        else
            include 'loginwithout.php';
        ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';

function loggedin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['u_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['u_id']))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
if(loggedin())
{
    $my_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
    $user_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username,firstname,lastname,user_level FROM users WHERE id='$my_id'");
    $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);
    $username = $run_user['username'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $firstname= $run_user['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
    $user_level = $run_user['user_level'];
    $_SESSION['user_level']=$user_level;
    $query_level = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name FROM levels WHERE id='$user_level'");
    $run_level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_level);
    $level_name = $run_level['name'];
    $_SESSION['level_name']=$level_name;
        echo session_id();
        echo $my_id;
}
?>
```

pop.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    if(empty($username) or empty($password))
    {
        echo "<p>Fields Empty</p>";
    }
    else{
        $check_login=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login)==1)
        {

            $run=mysqli_fetch_array($check_login);
            $u_id=$run['id'];
            $type=$run['type'];
            $user_level=$run['user_level'];
            if($type == 'd')
            { ?>
                <p class="dec">Your account has been deactivated</p>
            <?php }
            else
            {     
                        $_SESSION['user_level']=$user_level;
                        $_SESSION['u_id']=$u_id;
                        $_SESSION['firstname']=$run['firstname'];
echo session_id();
                }

        }
        else
        { ?>
            <p class="dec">You have entered either wrong Username or Password</p>
        <?php }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML form? In the Page pop.php?